# How to change node field label for some specific conditions?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

In preprocess_node I wrote this and when I do kint($variables['node']) I can see that label is set to "test", however on display it appears with the old label. How can I change the label name? Should it be in preprocess_node or some other hook? Or what else I should update, so it is actually displayed with label replacement?

```
    $node = &$variables['node'];
    if ($node->getType()=='training') {
      $term = reset($node->get('field_training_type')->referencedEntities());
    }
    if($term instanceof \Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface && $term->id() == 9) {
      $node->get('field_section_09')->getFieldDefinition()->setLabel('test');
      $variables['node'] = $node;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work for two reasons. First, you shouldn't change objects unless you want to save the changes  because they are shared across the entire Drupal application. Second, preprocess is for preparing variables printed in templates. Changing other variables has no effect.

So in `hook_preprocess_node` you can change only `$variables['content']`.

For most fields the label is stored in `#title` unless the field is built in a special way by callbacks:

```
$variables['content']['field_bar']['#title'] = 'Foo';
```

More straightforward, though, would be changing the label directly in `hook_preprocess_field`:

```
$variables['label'] = 'Foo';
```

which is then printed in the template as `{{ label }}`.

---

By the way, if you want to rewrite your code for field preprocess you find the node in this variable:

```
$node = $variables['element']['#object'];
```